# Infura React Native Expo Unhandled promise rejection: Error: missing response on sendTransaction

Tags: javascript, react-native, ethers.js

```
const SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('Ethereum.privatekey')
  const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(
    'ropsten',
    INFURA_PROJECT_ID
  );
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(JSON.parse(SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY), provider);
// console.log(signer)
  const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
    to,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
  });
  console.log("Mining transaction...");
  console.log(`https://${network}.etherscan.io/tx/${tx.hash}`);
  // Waiting for the transaction to be mined
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
  // The transaction is now on chain!
  console.log(`Mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);

  return tx;
```

I'm unable to send a transaction using react native infura ethers.js library. Keep getting the same error. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I seem to be running in a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution below fixes the issue.

https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/993#issuecomment-687869294

my versions are

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.6.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
```